# Creating an Item with the Tridion Event System

Tags: event-system, sites-9

I would like to make a new Structure Group when we create a new Folder.  In older versions of Tridion we might do this with the TDSE object.

I'm on Tridion Sites 9 and wanted to use something similar and tried with the following code.
     StructureGroup newSg = (StructureGroup) session.GetNewObject();

> Error CS0311  The type
>   'Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.StructureGroup' cannot
>   be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'Session.GetNewObject()'. There is no implicit reference conversion
>   from 'Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.StructureGroup'
>   to 'Tridion.ContentManager.SystemWideObject'.

Is my only option here to use the Tridion Core Service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the StructureGroup constructor to get a new SG, something like this:

```
StructureGroup newSg = new StructureGroup(session, parentSGTcmId);
```

Here is a snippet from the API docs:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nick!  I also found another way to solve it as well :)

Answer (score 4):

```
     [TcmExtension("NewStructureGroupForImageFolder")]
        public class NewStructureGroupForImageFolder : TcmExtension
        {
            public NewStructureGroupForImageFolder()
            {
                Subscribe();
            }

            private void Subscribe()
            {
                EventSystem.Subscribe<Folder, SaveEventArgs>(HandleFolderSave, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
            }

            private void HandleFolderSave(Folder folder, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
            {
                // create new Structure Group
                Publication pub = folder.ContextRepository as Publication;
                StructureGroup rootSg = pub.RootStructureGroup;
                StructureGroup newSg = rootSg.GetNewObject<StructureGroup>();
                newSg.Title = "a new structure group";
                newSg.Directory = "newsg";
                newSg.Save();
            }
      }
}
```